# Prove if $A$ is a square matrix and $AB=AC \Rightarrow B=C$, then $A$ is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra

**Prove**: if $A$ is a square matrix and $AB=AC$ implies $B=C$, then $A$ is invertible.

First year linear algebra, haven't gotten to determinants yet so the proof can't use determinants or anything beyond.

Edit: Solved, thanks.

Comment: Is it given that A is not the zero matrix?

Comment: @randomgirl: The given hypothesis fails for $A = 0$.

Comment: @anomaly Just trying to figure out why A(B-C)=0 couldn't imply A=0 or B-C=0 or both.

Comment: If A = 0, then AB = AC implies B = C is not satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the equation: $AX = 0$. We show $X = 0$. Write: $AX = A\cdot 0 \to X = 0$. Thus $A$ is invertible.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why $AX=0\implies X=0$ means $A$ is invertible?

Comment: Invertible matrix theorem: Null(A) = 0 iff A is invertible

Comment: This makes the most sense to me, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Rewrite it to $A(B-C) = 0  \Rightarrow B-C = 0$. By arbitrarity of $B$ and $C$, this condition basically implies $Av=0 \Rightarrow v=0, \forall v\in V$, which means that $A$ has nullspace $\{0\}$ and therefore is invertible.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you get from $AB=0\implies B=0$ to $Av=0\implies v=0$? What is your choice of $B$?

Comment: Since dimension of $B$ and $C$ is not specified, you can either take $B$ and $C$ to be vectors or in case you have fixed dimension for $B$ and $C$, just interpret the equation $A(B-C)=0 \rightarrow B-C=0$ column-wise and notice that we can choose the columns of $B$ and $C$ arbitrarily aswell.

Comment: I think this works.